# How do I add BarcodeFragment in code?

Tags: java, android, barcode, zxing

I want to use this lib: https://code.google.com/p/barcodefraglibv2/

But I can't figure out how to add BarcodeFragment in code.
Here's a sample:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements IScanResultHandler{
        BarcodeFragment fragment;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            fragment = new BarcodeFragment();
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.add(R.id.sample, fragment).commit();
            fragment.setScanResultHandler(this);

        }
    }
```

But I've got an error here:

```
ft.add(R.id.sample, fragment).commit();

The method add(int, Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, BarcodeFragment)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Try by getSupportFragmentManager()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an import problem. Your `Activity` doesn't use the support library, so `FragmentTransaction.add` is expecting a `Fragment` of type `android.app.Fragment` whereas you are providing a `BarcoreFragment` which extends `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`;

You can fix that by changing your `MainActivity` and make it implement `FragmentActivity` (see doc [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html)), then fixing your imports and making the following changes :

```
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.Activity;
MainActivity extends Activity
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

becomes

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```